# CloudWatch Insights By Date

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm trying to create a CloudWatch Insights query for Amazon Connect that will give me call counts by date. I'm able to get the number of log messages by date, however, I need to only count unique ContactId's. The query I have has many duplicated ContactId's since each time Connect logs to CloudWatch, it uses ContactId to tie all of the events related to a contact together. Is there a way to modify this query to only show the count of the unique ContactId?

```
filter @message like /ContactId/
| stats count(*) as callCount by toMillis(datefloor(1d))
| sort callCount desc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Embarassingly enough, almost immediately after posting this, I found my answer. count_distinct() gets me what I needed.

```
filter @message like /ContactId/
| stats count_distinct(ContactId) as callCount by toMillis(datefloor(1d))
| sort callCount desc
```

Comment: I think datefloor function expects two values; timestamp and period.
Thus the query would change to -

```filter @message like /ContactId/
| stats count_distinct(ContactId) as callCount by toMillis(datefloor(@timestamp, 1d))
| sort callCount desc```